# Can the "rate coefficient" of a chemical reaction really be called a "rate constant"?

Tags: kinetics

Can the rate coefficient of a reaction ever be referred to as a constant? To my limited knowledge, it cannot, because it is dependent on factors such as temperature (I'm getting that info from the Arrhenius Equation).

I'm looking for clarification here.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes the rate coefficient can be referred to as a "rate constant".
2. This is in fact a very, very common name for the rate coefficient.  Encyclopedia Brittanica has an entry for [rate constant](http://www.britannica.com/science/rate-constant).  Wikipedia has a [reaction rate constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reaction_rate_constant) page.  [Google's N-gram viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=rate+constant%2C+rate+coefficient&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Crate%20constant%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crate%20coefficient%3B%2Cc0) shows that "rate constant" is used more often in the English written corpus by a factor of more than five, relative to "rate coefficient".
3. The "constant" in rate constant refers to the fact that it does not vary with *concentration* of the reactants or products.  However, as you note, it could depend on other variables, such as temperature, pressure, catalyst, light, etc.